# The function is not returning an output under the if-else condition

Tags: python, list, reverse

After applying the queries on the given array the function is not returning the resulting array(res).

''' Reversing the Array according to the queries. Each pair of values in queries are the starting and ending indices of the given Array(Arr).

'''

```
Arr = [5,3,2,1,3]
Queries = [0,1,1,3,2,4]

def Reverse(Arr, Queries):
    res=[]
    for item in Arr:
        res.append(item)
    
    n = Queries[1]
    while(Queries[0] != n + 1):
        for i in range(Queries[0], Queries[1] + 1):
            res[Queries[0]] = Arr[Queries[1]]
            Queries[0] += 1
            Queries[1] -= 1
    
    Arr.clear()
    for item in res:
        Arr.append(item)
    Queries.pop(0)
    Queries.pop(0)
    #print(res)
    if len(Queries)== 0:
        return res 
    else:
        Reverse(Arr, Queries)

print(Reverse(Arr, Queries))
```

Comment: Note: building up the `res` list could just be `res = Arr.copy()`

Comment: What does `Reverse` return if `len(Queries)` does _not_ equal `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Reverse` function, if `len(Queries)` does *not* equal `0`, nothing is explicitly returned, so the function returns `None`.

Even then, you will get an `IndexError` because of you convoluted logic.

Instead, let's copy `arr` (which is a list, rather than an array). Then we'll iterate over the indices in `queries`. By giving `range` three arguments we specify where to start, where to stop, and the amount to increment by. If `queries` has length `6`, `i` will be `0`, `2`, and last `4`.

We can then use this to slice the list and reverse the specified sections.

```
def reverse(arr, queries):
  res = arr.copy()
  for i in range(0, len(queries), 2):
    res[queries[i]:queries[i+1]+1] = list(reversed(res[queries[i]:queries[i+1]+1]))
  return res
```